# Export a row with custom resolution

Tags: export, row

Let's create a custom color bar

```
Clear["Global`*"];

type1a = Graphics[{Green, Rectangle[{2, 1}, {4, 2}], Text[Style["Type 1a", Black, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 20], {3, 
  1.5}]}];
type1b = Graphics[{Darker[Green], Rectangle[{2, 1}, {4, 2}],Text[Style["Type 1b", Black, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 20], {3, 
  1.5}]}];
type2a = Graphics[{RGBColor[128/255, 128/255, 0], Rectangle[{2, 1}, {4, 2}], 
Text[Style["Type 2a", Black, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 20], {3, 
  1.5}]}];
type2b = Graphics[{Orange, Rectangle[{2, 1}, {4, 2}], Text[Style["Type 2b", Black, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 20], {3, 
  1.5}]}];
type3a = Graphics[{Magenta, Rectangle[{2, 1}, {4, 2}], Text[Style["Type 3a", Black, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 20], {3, 
  1.5}]}];
type3b = Graphics[{Pink, Rectangle[{2, 1}, {4, 2}], Text[Style["Type 3b", Black, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 20], {3, 
  1.5}]}];
type99 = Graphics[{Brown, Rectangle[{2, 1}, {4, 2}], Text[Style["Other", Black, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 20], {3, 
  1.5}]}];
esc = Graphics[{Cyan, Rectangle[{2, 1}, {4, 2}], Text[Style["Escaping", Black, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 20], {3, 
  1.5}]}];
cra1 = Graphics[{Blue, Rectangle[{2, 1}, {4, 2}], Text[Style["Collision 1", White, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 
  17], {3, 1.5}]}];
cra2 = Graphics[{Red, Rectangle[{2, 1}, {4, 2}], Text[Style["Collision 2", Black, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 
  17], {3, 1.5}]}];
cha = Graphics[{Yellow, Rectangle[{2, 1}, {4, 2}], Text[Style["Chaotic", Black, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 20], {3, 
  1.5}]}];

colbar = Row[{esc, cra1, cra2, type1a, type1b, type2a, type2b, type3a, type3b, cha, type99}]
```

Then I want to export it as a JPEG file with at least 500 dpi resolution.

```
E0 = Export["colorbar.jpg", colbar, ImageResolution -> 500];
```

However I get the following output

[image]

As you can see, the row breaks into two columns. Why? Is there a way to correctly export the row with the desired resolution?

**EDIT:**

I found a solution by simply manipulating the size of the row as

```
colbar = Row[{esc, col1, col2, type1a, type1b, type2a, type2b, type3a,
type3b, cha, type99}, ImageSize -> {1000, 50}]
```

Then I can export the row with the desired resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps instead of `Row`, use `ImageAssemble`:

```
Export["colorbar.jpg", 
 ImageAssemble[{esc, cra1, cra2, type1a, type1b, type2a, type2b, type3a, type3b, cha, type99}], 
 ImageResolution -> 500]
```

[image]

Since the text is small due to some detail of the rasterization, we will want to increase the font size.

```
type1a = Graphics[{Green, Rectangle[{2, 1}, {4, 2}], 
    Text[Style["Type 1a", Black, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 80], {3, 
      1.5}]}];
type1b = Graphics[{Darker[Green], Rectangle[{2, 1}, {4, 2}], 
    Text[Style["Type 1b", Black, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 80], {3, 
      1.5}]}];
type2a = Graphics[{RGBColor[128/255, 128/255, 0], 
    Rectangle[{2, 1}, {4, 2}], 
    Text[Style["Type 2a", Black, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 80], {3, 
      1.5}]}];
type2b = Graphics[{Orange, Rectangle[{2, 1}, {4, 2}], 
    Text[Style["Type 2b", Black, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 80], {3, 
      1.5}]}];
type3a = Graphics[{Magenta, Rectangle[{2, 1}, {4, 2}], 
    Text[Style["Type 3a", Black, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 80], {3, 
      1.5}]}];
type3b = Graphics[{Pink, Rectangle[{2, 1}, {4, 2}], 
    Text[Style["Type 3b", Black, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 80], {3, 
      1.5}]}];
type99 = Graphics[{Brown, Rectangle[{2, 1}, {4, 2}], 
    Text[Style["Other", Black, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 80], {3, 
      1.5}]}];
esc = Graphics[{Cyan, Rectangle[{2, 1}, {4, 2}], 
    Text[Style["Escaping", Black, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 80], {3, 
      1.5}]}];
cra1 = Graphics[{Blue, Rectangle[{2, 1}, {4, 2}], 
    Text[Style["Collision 1", White, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 
      70], {3, 1.5}]}];
cra2 = Graphics[{Red, Rectangle[{2, 1}, {4, 2}], 
    Text[Style["Collision 2", Black, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 
      70], {3, 1.5}]}];
cha = Graphics[{Yellow, Rectangle[{2, 1}, {4, 2}], 
    Text[Style["Chaotic", Black, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 80], {3, 
      1.5}]}];

Export["colorbar.jpg", 
 ImageAssemble[{esc, cra1, cra2, type1a, type1b, type2a, type2b, type3a, type3b, cha, type99}], 
 ImageResolution -> 500]
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, the text is also unreadable in my OS.

Comment: It seems that simply upping the font size will fix this issue.

Comment: This is a hack! There must be a way to use `Row` and `Export` correctly.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z I do not believe that using `Row` is the correct solution to this problem. `Row` is best used for displaying items inside your notebook while `ImageAssemble` is purpose built to catenate images.

Comment: I found a solution! See my edit!

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z I'm glad you found a solution that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try `Grid` instead.

```
colbar = Grid[{{esc, cra1, cra2, type1a, type1b, type2a, type2b, 
    type3a, type3b, cha, type99}}, ItemSize -> Full]
```